# callback function in flutter is giving error

Tags: flutter, callback, parent-child

I have 2 stateful widgets. A class calls B class where the state is returned by a callback function. each time I get this error .
ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).

code is as below
class A

'''

```
class _BodyState extends State<Body> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isProcess = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return signupBody(context);
  }

  _updateMyState(bool state) {
    setState(() {
      isProcess = state;
    });
  }

  Widget signupBody(BuildContext context) {
    return isProcess
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : SafeArea(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.04), // 4%
                      Text("Register Account", style: headingStyle),
                      Text(
                        "Complete your details or continue \nwith social media",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.08),
                      SignUpForm(
                          isMyProcess: false, parentAction: _updateMyState),
                      SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.08),
                      
                      SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
                      Text(
                        'By continuing your confirm that you agree \nwith our Term and Condition',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }}
```

'''
Class B
'''

```
class SignUpForm extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isMyProcess;

   final ValueChanged<bool> parentAction;

  SignUpForm({ required this.isMyProcess,required this.parentAction});
  @override
  SignUpFormState createState() => SignUpFormState();
}

class SignUpFormState extends State<SignUpForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Formbuild(context);
    
  }

  Widget Formbuild(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildFirstNameFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildPhoneNumberFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildEmailFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildPasswordFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildConformPassFormField(),
          FormError(errors: errors),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(40)),
          DefaultButton(
            text: "Continue",
            press: () {
              print(signupRequestModel.toJson());
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                _formKey.currentState!.save();
                // if all are valid then go to success screen
                request_function();
                // Navigator.pushNamed(context, CompleteProfileScreen.routeName);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  request_function() async {

    widget.parentAction(true);
    APIService apiService = new APIService();
    apiService.signup(signupRequestModel).then((value) async {
      if (value != null) {
        // setState(() {
        //   isApiCallProcess = false;
        // });
        widget.parentAction(false);
        if (value.token.isNotEmpty) {
          print(value.token);

         Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignInScreen.routeName);
          await this._showToastDone(context);
        } else {

      
          this._showToast(context, value.error);
          print(value.error);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

'''

what I understand is that as I press the continue button class B returns to class A and the state is no more there. am I right??  what can be the possible solutions for it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can change your callback function type from a **ValueChanged** to just a simple **Function?**, and you can call it the same way, cuz all you want is just call the method reference and pass a parameter through it, right?

You can follow this DartPad Gist to see an example. Hit "Run" and see how I pass the function as a **Function** https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/b256ba999b5be9eecba0c7abf28ee83f. Run this in DartPad.

Comment: yes i want to update the value of bool from class b to class a, to add circularprogressbar

Comment: First check what I suggested above first and verify that switching it to a Function works for you. Then if you need help with the circular progress indicator maybe you can add it as a separate question. Good luck!

Comment: how to convert valuechanged to function??

Comment: In your **SignupForm** class (Class B) just change **final ValueChanged<bool> parentAction;** to **final Function parentAction;** and that's it.